# Selecting nth column X=np.array(data.ix[:,...]

Tags: numpy

The following code is for data in the first four columns of a numpy array.

```
X=np.array(data.ix[:,0:4])
```

What if I want the 1st, 7th and 8th?

Comment: You mean `X=np.array(data.ix[:,[06,7]]) `

Comment: What's the purpose of the `np.array()` wrapper?  What's `data`, `data.ix`? Looks array like?  Or is it a pandas object?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a list for column indices:

```
In [9]: ix=np.arange(20).reshape(2,10)

In [10]: ix
Out[10]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

In [11]: ix[:,[0,6,7]]
Out[11]: 
array([[ 0,  6,  7],
       [10, 16, 17]])
```

Comment: rather than using random numbers, use a sequence that one can interpret like... ix = np.arange(30).reshape(3,10) .... then slice ... ix[:,[0, 6, 7]] ... which yields ... array([[ 0,  6,  7],  [10, 16, 17],   [20, 26, 27]])

Comment: @NaN Thanks for suggestion. Modified now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to slice a Dataframe to a numpy array. If that's the case, you can use:

```
x=data.iloc[:,[0,6,7]].values
```

`ix` is going to be deprecated in the future, so use iloc instead.